# What is the meaning of the two "stint" in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm reading a Wikipedia's post https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaq%E2%80%93Kobe_feud#cite_note-lakers_history-3.

> The team's lockout-shortened 50-game 1998–99 season included a brief
>   **stint** as a player by Dennis Rodman, the firing of head coach Harris,
>   and the interim head coaching **stint** of former Laker player Kurt
>   Rambis.[3]

There are two stints on it. I tried very hard but still couldn't get the meaning of it.

Can someone tell me what do they mean?

Comment: A [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stint): *a period of time spent at a particular activity*.  Does this require further explanation?

Comment: Still don’t quite understand... especially the last part.

Comment: The last part about Kurt Rambis? Because of an unusual season involving the lockout, they had a former player take over coaching duties for a brief period. I.e. the stint.

Answer (score 1):

Stint there means "period of time"

Comment: ...but in the context of time spent in a particular job or activity (_a brief stint as a player_).

Comment: Please add supporting references to your answer. A dictionary reference in the answer itself, and a link to where that reference is found.

Comment: No problem http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/stint